# Problem with customized layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

I'm trying to find a way to test whether or not the current page is a splash page because my layered navigation is crashing when I visit a splash page (fishpig extension).  The code that is in /web/app/design/frontend/default/'mytheme'/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

Here is the code

```
    <?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav">
        <div class="block-title">
            <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?> </span></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
            <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>




            <?php
                    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                    ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
                    $valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
                    ->setStoreFilter(0, false);
                    $mfgmatch=0;
                    $preparedManufacturers = array();            
                    foreach($valuesCollection as $value) {
                        $preparedManufacturers[$value->getOptionId()] = $value->getValue();
                    }   


                    if (count($preparedManufacturers)) {

                        foreach($preparedManufacturers as $optionId => $value) {
                            //echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
                            $mfg_url=str_replace(" ","-",$value);
                            $mfg_url=strtolower($mfg_url);
                            $mfg_count=substr_count(curPageURL(),$mfg_url);
                            //echo $value." ".$mfg_count."<br>";
                            if ($mfg_count >=1 ) {
                                $mfgmatch++;
                            }
                        }

                    }
            ?>              







                <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                    <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                    <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount() 
                            && $_filter->getName()=="Category" 
                            && substr_count(curPageURL(), 'catalogsearch')==0
                            && substr_count(curPageURL(), '?cat')==0
                            && $mfgmatch==0)://exclude manufacturer pages from showing category in layered nav?>
                        <dt id="<?php echo $_filter->getName()?> parent" onclick="GAccordian('<?php echo $_filter->getName(); ?>');" style="cursor:pointer; background-color:#a2b2c3; background-image:url(/skin/frontend/default/wsf/images/accordian-open.png); border-bottom:none; "><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                        <!--magic subcategory code-->
                        <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
                        <?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
                        <?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
                        <?php $subcats=$currentCategory->getChildrenCategories();?>

                        <dd id="<?php echo $_filter->getName(); ?> open" style="background-color:#a2b2c3; display:block;">
                        <ol>
                        <?php foreach ($subcats as $subcat): ?>
                            <?php if ($subcat->getLevel()==($currentCategory->getLevel()+3)): ?> 


                                <li>

                                <a href="<?php echo curPageURL()."?cat=".$subcat->getID(); ?>">
                                    <?php echo $subcat->getName();?>
                                </a>
                                <?php echo " "; ?>
                                <?php                       
                                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcat->getID());
                                $_product = $_category->getProductCollection();
                                $_product->setVisibility(array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,          Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));
                                $_product->addFieldToFilter('status',Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                                ?>

                                (<?php echo $_product->count(); ?>)

                                </li>




                            <?php endif ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                        </ol>
                        </dd>
                        <!--end magic subcategory code-->   
                        <!--<dd id="<?php //echo $_filter->getName()?>"><?php //echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>-->



                    <?php elseif ($_filter->getItemsCount() && $_filter->getName()!="Category")://only for non Category sections of layered nav ?>  
                        <dt id="<?php echo $_filter->getName()?> parent" onclick="GAccordian('<?php echo $_filter->getName(); ?>');" style="cursor:pointer"><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                        <dd id="<?php echo $_filter->getName()?>"><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </dl>
                <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    function curPageURL() {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        return $pageURL;
    }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GAccordian(id)
{
    var openid=id+' open';
    //var parentid=id+" parent";
    //var openparentid=id+' parent open';
    var open=document.getElementById(openid);
    //var openparent=document.getElementById(openparentid);
    var imgPath = new String(); 
    imgPath = document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.backgroundImage; 
    pathArray = window.location.href.split( '/' );
    protocol = pathArray[0];
    host = pathArray[2];
    url = protocol + '//' + host;

    if(open)
    {
        document.getElementById(openid).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.backgroundImage = 
            "url("+url+"/skin/frontend/default/wsf/images/accordian-closed.png)"; 
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.backgroundColor = '';
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.borderBottom = '1px dotted gray';
        document.getElementById(openid).id=id;//must remain last
        //document.getElementById(openparentid).id=parentid;//must remain last
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = '#a2b2c3';
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.backgroundImage =   
            "url("+url+"/skin/frontend/default/wsf/images/accordian-open.png)"; 
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.backgroundColor = '#a2b2c3';
        document.getElementById(id+" parent").style.borderBottom = 'none';
        document.getElementById(id).id=id+" open";  //must remain last
        //document.getElementById(openparentid).id=parentid+" open"; //must remain last

    }


}
</script>
```

Comment: What is a splash page?

Answer (score 2):

Open the spalsh page layout XML file and remove the left layered navigation navigation block using the code `<remove name="catalog.leftnav" />`